# Utilizing a loop or automated method instead of manually typing out each iloc position to change dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Summary: I want to be able to recreate my function without having to manually type out each individual iloc and using if/elif for scalability for situations when the groups get too large to handle

I have a sample table df_stack_exchange

```
data_stack_exchange = {'store': ['A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'worker': [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
        'boxes': [105, 90, 100, 80, 10, 200, 70, 210, 50, 0],
        'optimal_boxes': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df_stack_exchange = pandas.DataFrame(data_stack_exchange)
```

|  | store | worker | boxes | optimal_boxes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 | 105 | 0 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 90 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 100 | 0 |
| 3 | C | 1 | 80 | 0 |
| 4 | C | 2 | 10 | 0 |
| 5 | C | 3 | 200 | 0 |
| 6 | D | 1 | 70 | 0 |
| 7 | D | 2 | 210 | 0 |
| 8 | D | 3 | 50 | 0 |
| 9 | D | 4 | 0 | 0 |

Worker priority is in numerical order and I want to assign them a maximum of 100 boxes until there is no more to assign. The only condition is that if there is only one worker available (store A) then the single worker gets all the boxes even if it is greater than 100. **See below for the expected dataframe**

|  | store | worker | boxes | optimal_boxes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 | 105 | 105 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 90 | 100 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 100 | 90 |
| 3 | C | 1 | 80 | 100 |
| 4 | C | 2 | 10 | 100 |
| 5 | C | 3 | 200 | 90 |
| 6 | D | 1 | 70 | 100 |
| 7 | D | 2 | 210 | 100 |
| 8 | D | 3 | 50 | 100 |
| 9 | D | 4 | 0 | 30 |

I created the following function which yields my expected outcome BUT it is not sustainable as I have to manually type out each iloc. I want to be able to recreate this function with a loop or have it be able to scale without having to keep on adding elifs. It is not a scalable solution for when group sizes become 10+ instead of the current max size of 4 (store D)

```
def box_optimizer(x):
    if x['optimal_boxes'].count() == 1:
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[0] = x['boxes'].sum()
        return x
    elif x['optimal_boxes'].count() == 2:
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[0] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[1] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        return x
    elif x['optimal_boxes'].count() == 3:
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[0] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[1] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[2] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        return x
    elif x['optimal_boxes'].count() == 4:
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[0] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[1] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[2] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum())
        x['optimal_boxes'].iloc[3] += numpy.where(x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum() > 100, 100, x['boxes'].sum() - x['optimal_boxes'].sum()) 
        return x

df_stack_exchange_function = pandas.DataFrame(df_stack_exchange.groupby('store', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(box_optimizer))

# the expected dataframe output
df_stack_exchange_function
```

Comment: What if two workers have more than 200 boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, just sum the boxes, divide the total by 100 to get the number of workers with a full box, assign the rest to the last worker:

```
def assign_boxes(s):
    total = s.sum()
    d = min(total // 100, len(s)-1)
    return [100]*d+[total - 100*d]+[0]*(len(s)-d-1)

df['optimal_boxes'] = df.groupby('store')['boxes'].transform(assign_boxes)
```

Output:

```
  store  worker  boxes  optimal_boxes
0     A       1    105            105
1     B       1     90            100
2     B       2    100             90
3     C       1     80            100
4     C       2     10            100
5     C       3    200             90
6     D       1     70            100
7     D       2    210            100
8     D       3     50            100
9     D       4      0             30
```

Explanation:

```
[100]*d           # number of workers with 100
[total - 100*d]   # next worker gets all rest
[0]*(len(s)-d-1)  # in case there are too many workers, pad with 0s
```

Detailed explanation:

```
# example 1
s = pd.Series([70, 110, 50, 0])
total = s.sum()  # 230

# min (230//100, 3)
# min (2, 3) = 2
d = min(total // 100, len(s)-1)

out = ([100]*d          # [100] * 2 -> [100, 100]
      +[total - 100*d]  # [230 - 100*2] -> [30]
      +[0]*(len(s)-d-1) # [0]*(4-2-1) -> [0]
      ) # [100, 100, 30, 0]

# example 2
s = pd.Series([70, 210, 50, 0])
total = s.sum()  # 330

# min (330//100, 3)
# min (3, 3) = 3
d = min(total // 100, len(s)-1)

out = ([100]*d          # [100] * 3 -> [100, 100, 100]
      +[total - 100*d]  # [330 - 100*3] -> [30]
      +[0]*(len(s)-d-1) # [0]*(4-3-1) -> []
      ) # [100, 100, 100, 30]
```

Comment: @qwerty12 I added a breakdown of the logic for 2 examples

Comment: Studied your answer more in jupyter notebook and was able to understand hence the deleted comment. Nonetheless really appreciate the detailed explanation. Cheers

Comment: would you know how to convert:
df['optimal_boxes'] = df.groupby('store')['boxes'].transform(assign_boxes)
into its equivalent Pyspark counterpart? Struggling to do it as I keep on getting groupeddata object is not subscriptable error

Comment: @qwerty12 I don't and this would be a different question. You should ask it.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve by using iterating over the workers within each group using loop. Here's a modified version of your function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_stack_exchange = {'store': ['A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                       'worker': [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
                       'boxes': [105, 90, 100, 80, 10, 200, 70, 210, 50, 0],
                       'optimal_boxes': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df_stack_exchange = pd.DataFrame(data_stack_exchange)

def box_optimizer(x):
    total_boxes = x['boxes'].sum()
    num_workers = x['worker'].nunique()

    if num_workers == 1:
        x['optimal_boxes'] = total_boxes
    else:
        remaining_boxes = total_boxes
        for _, row in x.iterrows():
            available_boxes = min(100, remaining_boxes)
            x.loc[row.name, 'optimal_boxes'] += available_boxes
            remaining_boxes -= available_boxes
            if remaining_boxes <= 0:
                break

    return x

df_stack_exchange_function = df_stack_exchange.groupby('store', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(box_optimizer)

print(df_stack_exchange_function)


store  worker  boxes  optimal_boxes
0     A       1    105            105
1     B       1     90            100
2     B       2    100             90
3     C       1     80            100
4     C       2     10            100
5     C       3    200             90
6     D       1     70            100
7     D       2    210            100
8     D       3     50            100
9     D       4      0             30
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is amazing! Could you explain the else part?

Comment: That's not a very good approach, you don't need to loop to solve this, you can directly compute the number of workers with 100 and assign the rest

Comment: Instead of using multiple elif statements, you can use an else statement to handle the case where num_workers > 1. The elif statements in your original code were handling different cases for the number of workers in a store (1, 2, 3, or 4). In the modified function, the else statement effectively covers all cases where num_workers > 1.

Comment: @Umar have you use AI to assist you in writing this answer? If yes which one?

Comment: I was trying to solve it, loop and dataframe, I am learning python, i followed his code